# CMake does not set compilation options in <ClCompile> for the generated Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Consider empty `main.cpp` with the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test)
if (MSVC)
    add_compile_options(/W4 /WX /JMC /OptionDoesNotExist)
endif()
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

I call `cmake .` to generate Visual Studio project:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.36.32532.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.36.32532.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: [REDACTED]
```

However, the generated `main.vcxproj` only lists `/OptionDoesNotExist` as compilation options. Why are real options ignored and not added anywhere? Here is an excerpt from `main.vcxproj`:

```xml
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalOptions>%(AdditionalOptions) /OptionDoesNotExist</AdditionalOptions>
      <AssemblerListingLocation>$(IntDir)</AssemblerListingLocation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake recognizes most Visual Studio options and sets them up in the project file in Visual Studio-specific way, not as merely compilation options. There are some lists in the [`Templates/MSBuild/FlagTables/v143_CL.json`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/63fc43d12955f0f5b55a2fafa4507e9fb05d98fa/Templates/MSBuild/FlagTables/v143_CL.json), e.g.:

```json
  {
    "name": "SupportJustMyCode",
    "switch": "JMC-",
    "comment": "Support Just My Code Debugging",
    "value": "false",
    "flags": []
  },
  {
    "name": "SupportJustMyCode",
    "switch": "JMC",
    "comment": "Support Just My Code Debugging",
    "value": "true",
    "flags": []
  },
```

Whenever CMake sees `/JMC` or `/JMC-` as a compilation option, it removes it from the command line and instead sets the `<SupportJustMyCode>` value in `.vcxproj` directly. Not only that changes compilation options in the end, it also changes the "Support Just My Code Debugging" property of the project. That way you get a Visual Studio project that feels more native.

Similarly, `/W4` sets `<WarningLevel>` to `Level4`, and `/WX` sets `<TreatWarningAsError>` to `true`.

All in all, all compilation options are actually listed, just not in the exact same way they were:

```xml
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalOptions>%(AdditionalOptions) /OptionDoesNotExist</AdditionalOptions>    <!-- Unrecognized options only -->
      <AssemblerListingLocation>$(IntDir)</AssemblerListingLocation>
      <BasicRuntimeChecks>EnableFastChecks</BasicRuntimeChecks>
      <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
      <ExceptionHandling>Sync</ExceptionHandling>
      <InlineFunctionExpansion>Disabled</InlineFunctionExpansion>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebugDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
      <RuntimeTypeInfo>true</RuntimeTypeInfo>
      <SupportJustMyCode>true</SupportJustMyCode>  <!-- /JMC -->
      <TreatWarningAsError>true</TreatWarningAsError>  <!-- /WX -->
      <UseFullPaths>false</UseFullPaths>
      <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>  <!-- /W4 -->
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>%(PreprocessorDefinitions);WIN32;_WINDOWS;CMAKE_INTDIR="Debug"</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ObjectFileName>$(IntDir)</ObjectFileName>
    </ClCompile>
```